# Error: Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead

Tags: salesforcedx

I need a help here, i am trying to deploy the Aura components by using Azure Devops CICD for salesforce. i am getting the error :

> Error: Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead.

I tried to update in my incremental script not sure where I am going wrong. Kindly, help me with a solution. I am able to deploy if .cmp extension but unable to deploy.js files alone.
Basically what I want to try is if i make any change in .js file it should deploy that alone rather looking for whole Aura folder.

My inceremental script

```
 $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
    if ($extn -eq ".cls" -or  $extn -eq ".page"  -or $extn -eq ".trigger" -or $extn -eq ".js" -or $extn -eq ".cmp"-or $extn -or $extn -eq ".css" -or $extn -eq ".js-meta.xml")
    {
        echo "inside meta"
        $metafile = $file + "-meta.xml"
        echo FA|xcopy $metafile temp\$metafile
        echo $temp
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Basically what I want to try is if i make any change in .js file it should deploy that alone rather looking for whole Aura folder.

You can't do that. An Aura JavaScript file is not a deployable unit via the Metadata API. You need to deploy the entire component bundle.